# How to construct relative url, given two absolute urls in Python

Tags: python, urlparse

Is there a builtin function to get url like this: `../images.html` given a base url like this: `http://www.example.com/faq/index.html` and a target url such as `http://www.example.com/images.html`

I checked urlparse module. What I want is counterpart of the urljoin() function.

Comment: do you mean something like `wget --convert-links`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [urlparse.urlparse](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse) to find the paths, and the posixpath version of [os.path.relname](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath) to find the relative path.

(Warning: This works for Linux, but may not for Windows):

```
import urlparse
import sys
import posixpath

def relurl(target,base):
    base=urlparse.urlparse(base)
    target=urlparse.urlparse(target)
    if base.netloc != target.netloc:
        raise ValueError('target and base netlocs do not match')
    base_dir='.'+posixpath.dirname(base.path)
    target='.'+target.path
    return posixpath.relpath(target,start=base_dir)

tests=[
    ('http://www.example.com/images.html','http://www.example.com/faq/index.html','../images.html'),
    ('http://google.com','http://google.com','.'),
    ('http://google.com','http://google.com/','.'),
    ('http://google.com/','http://google.com','.'),
    ('http://google.com/','http://google.com/','.'), 
    ('http://google.com/index.html','http://google.com/','index.html'),
    ('http://google.com/index.html','http://google.com/index.html','index.html'), 
    ]

for target,base,answer in tests:
    try:
        result=relurl(target,base)
    except ValueError as err:
        print('{t!r},{b!r} --> {e}'.format(t=target,b=base,e=err))
    else:
        if result==answer:
            print('{t!r},{b!r} --> PASS'.format(t=target,b=base))
        else:
            print('{t!r},{b!r} --> {r!r} != {a!r}'.format(
                t=target,b=base,r=result,a=answer))
```

Comment: doesn't this depend on current operating system? I am getting ..\\images.html in win 7.

Comment: @yasar11732: use posixpath.relpath()

Comment: just set up a linux virtual machine that exposes an xmlrpc method that returns you the correct result of the function.. :P :) [ok, I didn't thought of different path separators, now I'm trying to find another way to do that//]

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: looks like `posixpath` is only available on UNIX.. same problem as above: http://docs.python.org/library/undoc.html?highlight=posixpath

Comment: @redShadow: it is available everywhere, but on Unix it also called `os.path`. On Windows you must call it `posixpath`.

Comment: @J.F.S. Yep - just tried that, you are right. The `os` module imports (`posixpath`|`ntpath`|...) as `path` depending on the current platform -- or `sys.builtin_module_names`, but all the implementations are still available. Didn't know that, +1.

Comment: `posixpath.relpath()` calls `posixpath.abspath()` which calls `os.getcwd()` It leads to incorrect results http://paste.pocoo.org/show/wwrINjNV74wL6pSMBQFB/ on Windows. It might be better to copy [relpath() from posixpath.py](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/posixpath.py#l400) and remove `abspath()` calls due to `relurl()` expects absolute urls.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion but my example is incorrect. It passes `'images.html'` instead of `'/images.html'`. [Relative path won't work even on Unix.](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/EHOhqgmdBn1DHls8h147/). So `posixpath.relpath()` should be used everywhere with the assertion that `target.startswith('/') and base_dir.startswith('/')` (it is not always true e.g., `url='http://google.com'` → `target=''`).

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: Thank you for your help. Instead of asserting `startswith('/')` I stumbled upon adding '.' in front of `base_dir` and `target`. This is the only way I've found to pass all tests on linux (see above). I'm giving up on supporting Windows since I don't have a way to test code there.

Comment: All tests pass on win7 with python 2.7

Answer (score 5):

The first solutions that comes to mind is:

```
>>> os.path.relpath('/images.html', os.path.dirname('/faq/index.html'))
'../images.html'
```

Of course, this requires URL parsing -> domain name comparison (!!) -> path rewriting if that's the case -> re-adding query and fragment.

### Edit: a more complete version

```
import urlparse
import posixpath

def relative_url(destination, source):
    u_dest = urlparse.urlsplit(destination)
    u_src = urlparse.urlsplit(source)

    _uc1 = urlparse.urlunsplit(u_dest[:2]+tuple('' for i in range(3)))
    _uc2 = urlparse.urlunsplit(u_src[:2]+tuple('' for i in range(3)))

    if _uc1 != _uc2:
        ## This is a different domain
        return destination

    _relpath = posixpath.relpath(u_dest.path, posixpath.dirname(u_src.path))

    return urlparse.urlunsplit(('', '', _relpath, u_dest.query, u_dest.fragment)
```

Then

```
>>> relative_url('http://www.example.com/images.html', 'http://www.example.com/faq/index.html')
'../images.html'
>>> relative_url('http://www.example.com/images.html?my=query&string=here#fragment', 'http://www.example.com/faq/index.html')
'../images.html?my=query&string=here#fragment'
>>> relative_url('http://www.example.com/images.html', 'http://www2.example.com/faq/index.html')
'http://www.example.com/images.html'
>>> relative_url('https://www.example.com/images.html', 'http://www.example.com/faq/index.html')
'https://www.example.com/images.html'
```

Edit: now using the `posixpath` implementation of `os.path` to make it work under windows too.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
import urlparse

def makeRelativeUrl(sourceUrl, targetUrl):
  '''

  :param sourceUrl: a string
  :param targetUrl: a string
  :return: the path to target url relative to first or targetUrl if at different net location
  '''
  # todo test
  parsedSource = urlparse.urlparse(sourceUrl)
  parsedTarget = urlparse.urlparse(targetUrl)

  if parsedSource.netloc == parsedTarget.netloc:
    # if target on same path but lower than source url
    if parsedTarget.path.startswith(parsedSource.path):
      return parsedTarget.path.replace(parsedSource.path, '.')
    # on same path
    elif parsedTarget.path.rsplit('/', 1)[0] == parsedSource.path.rsplit('/', 1)[0]:
      return './' + parsedTarget.path.rsplit('/', 1)[1]
    # same netloc, varying paths
    else:
      path = ''
      upCount = 0
      for item in list(itertools.izip_longest(parsedSource.path.rsplit('/'), parsedTarget.path.rsplit('/'))):
        if item[0] == item[1]:
          pass
        else:
          if item[0] is not None:
            upCount += 1
          if item[1] is not None:
            path += item[1] + '/'
      return upCount * '../' + path
  else:
    return targetUrl


if __name__ == '__main__':
  '''
  "tests" :p
  '''
  url1 = 'http://coolwebsite.com/questions/bobobo/bo/bo/1663807/how-can-i-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel-in-python'
  url2 = 'http://coolwebsite.com/questions/126524/iterate-a-list-with-indexes-in-python'

  print url1
  print url2
  print 'second relative to second:'
  print makeRelativeUrl(url1, url2)

  url1 = 'http://coolwebsite.com/questions/1663807/how-can-i-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel-in-python'
  url2 = 'http://coolwebsite.com/questions/1663807/bananas'

  print url1
  print url2
  print 'second relative to first:'
  print makeRelativeUrl(url1, url2)

  url1 = 'http://coolwebsite.com/questions/1663807/fruits'
  url2 = 'http://coolwebsite.com/questions/1663807/fruits/berries/bananas'

  print url1
  print url2
  print 'second relative to first:'
  print makeRelativeUrl(url1, url2)
```

Run 'tests' to see if it works :P